# R qplot error message: The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, shapes, scatter

I am trying to do a qplot to do a scatter plot matrix.

```
qplot(X, Y, data=Customers, shape = Z,facets=ColA~ColB, size=I(3), xlab="X",ylab="Y")
```

Where Z is a categorical variable with more than 6 levels.

I get this error message:

"The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate. Consider specifying shapes manually if you must have them"

My question is, how do I specify shape manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off calling the plot through ggplot directly and setting the shape scale manually instead of using qplot:

```
ggplot(data=Customers, aes(x=X, y=Y, shape=Z)) + 
         geom_point(size=1) +
         labs(x="X",y="Y")+ 

         scale_shape_manual(values=c(4,29,30,53,23,53,64,53,23)) + 
         facet_grid(ColA~ColB)
```

This page has a legend of all the available shapes for plotting in ggplot: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-point-shapes-best-tips/

Qplot is a "quick and dirty" method for making plots, and calling the plot commands through ggplot allows you to have more control over the output.

Answer (score 0):

My first tip would be to avoid `qplot`. The short syntax is doing nobody any favors. Try

```
ggplot(Customers, aes(x = X, y = Y, shape = Z)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y") +
  facet_grid(ColA ~ ColB)
```

and you can now easily read and add extra layers, i.e. manual colors. See [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) on how to specify colors in various ways.

```
ggplot(Customers, aes(x = X, y = Y, shape = Z)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", _more_colors_)) +
  facet_grid(ColA ~ ColB)
```

my favorite is

```
scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Comment: It's shape, not color.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roman. That was very helpful. I will use your approach as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers fh432. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.